# User authentication with CAS in symfony2 and BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle (or other suggestions)

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, cas

I am doing a web project with symfony2 that involves a CAS server: http://www.jasig.org/cas unfortunately I cannot make it working. I have tried several configurations and anything of what I do is correct. This is the flux that I am expecting to do for any user that wants to be logged:

1. A user wants to login in my system
2. My system redirects somehow the users to the cas server login web page to login with user credentials.
3. After a valid login, cas server login webpage redirects user back to my system.
4. My system knows if the user is well logged or not based on protocol mechanisms.

I have found a Bundle BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle (https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle) for symfony2 but I am not sure if it works properly since it looks a little bit old. Following the instructions from the rep, here are all my configurations:

For the config.yml

```
be_simple_sso_auth:
    admin_sso:
        protocol:
            id: cas
            version: 2
        server:
            id: cas
            login_url: https://cas_server.fi/cas/login
            validation_url: https://cas_server.fi/cas/serviceValidate
```

For the security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        my_firewall:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            trusted_sso:
                manager: admin_sso
                login_action: false
                create_users: true
                created_users_roles: [ROLE_ADMIN]
                check_path: /
```

The cas server provided me two .crt files that I have already installed in my Ubuntu 13.10. Or at least I what I think... however any of this previous configurations do not seem to want these certificates since I cannot specify where the bundle can find them. Anyway it does not work yet so this step maybe is irrelevant.

So, what happens now is the next:

1. User access to */* for first time
2. My system redirect him to */login* (as far as I understand it is the default direction...)

To manage this */login* I have in routing.yml in my own bundle:

```
ss_web_login:
    path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle:TrustedSso:login }
```

I have checked this controller and it looks like it draws an anchor to "somewhere" (I guess is the login form of my cas server.

Let's continue... as I said, the user is being redirected to /login but I get an error:

```
Controller "BeSimple\SsoAuthBundle\Controller\TrustedSsoController::loginAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$manager" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

It happens because the BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle:TrustedSso:login expects different parameters:

```
public function loginAction(Manager $manager, Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception = null)
```

But nobody is passing these parameters that it expects. What should I do?

Please, if you have ANY other suggestion about make this working I will really appreciate. Even to recommend me the use of another cas client or different implementation (but I need to make it working).

Thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a question to the problem you asked in May. But I'm at the moment "fighting" with Symfony 2 and the same library. 

I've got the same problem. Did you find solution to your problem?

Comment: No, I was not able :( I gave up. I implemented by myself the authentication in every action... the phpcas library breaks the symfony2 flux but at least I finally achieve make it working.

Comment: That's bad. But I'm thinking about the same thing. So you are checking credentials in all of your controllers?

How do you import jasig/phpcas. Do you have composer version of this lib? I coudn't find it. So you've just copied whole library to /vendor/ dir?

Comment: What I have done is just a class that has a method "identify me" which uses the code of phpcas library code as usual. It will completely break the symfony2 flux in the sense of if the user is not logged, then it will be redirected and so on. If the logging is correct, the flux will just continue (in that point I create my own User object). This is not a solution, is is even quite far for a workaround.... but it just worked.

Comment: Pure engineering as you can see...

Comment: Thanks. I did the same yesterday and it's working great. But like you said. Solution without breaking symfony flux would be awesome. I've checked all cas libs. None of them is working.

Comment: Any news on this topic ???

Answer (score 0):

As far as this error - Controller "BeSimple\SsoAuthBundle\Controller\TrustedSsoController::loginAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$manager" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

is concerned, the actual answer to resolve/fix this is to provide the correct user provider in your security.yml providers key and use it right in the provider key of your firewall.

For eg. providers:
           administrators:
              entity: { class: UserBundle\Entity\User }

And under the required firewall, make use of provider: administrators as the key:value.

This issue gets resolved.

Also note, anonymous key needs to be commented. Anonymous user key does not populate the $manager